# PHP - Both if and else conditions are executed on foreach loop

Tags: php, sql, if-statement, foreach, echo

```
$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT(title) as title FROM table WHERE title IS NOT NULL")->fetchAll();
foreach ($stmt as $tag) {
    if ($tag['title'] == 'home'){
        print_r($tag);
        echo 'tag home';                
    } elseif ($tag['title'] == 'contact'){
        print_r($tag);
        echo 'tag contact';              
    }
}
```

The result is the same on all pages:

```
Array ( [title] => home [0] => home ) 
tag home
Array ( [title] => contact [0] => contact ) 
tag contact
```

The desired results:

- When on `home` page   : `tag home`
- When on `contact` page: `tag contact`

Comment: Your `SELECT` query returns all titles, not just the title related to the current page.

Comment: Do you also have `print_r($tag)` in the code?

Comment: You're executing the `if` for the first row, and the `elseif` for the second row.

Comment: @Barmar You mean `print_r($tag)` on the loop? the result: string(6) "home" string(4) "contact" and - `print_r($tag)` into the `if`: string(6) "home" - `print_r($tag)` into the `else`: string(6) "contact"

Comment: I was asking because you said that the result showed `Array ( [title] => home [0] => home )`. That looks like the output of `print_r()`, but I can't see where that's coming from in the code that you posted.

Comment: @Barmar Alright, i updated my question.

Comment: Why do you expect this code to print different results on different pages? Nothing it does depends on the page, it's just printing whatever is in the table.

Comment: @Barmar Because a friend told me that i needed to put a `if` and `else` conditions into a `loop`. I'm still learning, so i just belivied on him. Then which type of code i need?

Comment: Is there a variable that indicates whether the current page is the home or contact page? Compare `$tag['title']` to that variable.

Comment: @Barmar Actually not, i just have it on my columns on DB, example: column `title` = home.

Comment: Then how do you expect to get a different result depending on which page you're on? You need to do something different on each page.

Comment: The database doesn't know which page you're on, so it can't send different results.

Comment: @Barmar Got it, **"Then how do you expect to get a different result depending on which page you're on"** I thought my `if` and `else` condition would handle it. Could you please tell me how do i do it?

Comment: Why did you think that? It's `$tag['title']` is the title of the current row of the table. It has nothing to do with what page you're on. You need something that knows which page you're on. Like a variable `$current_page = "home";`, then you can do `if ($current_page == "home" && $tag['title'] == "home")`

Comment: But why wouldn't you just put `WHERE title = '$current_page'` into the query?

Comment: @Barmar Nice, is it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a variable on the page that indicates which page it is. On the home page do:

```
$current_page = "home";
```

and on the contact page do:

```
$current_page = "contact";
```

Then you can just select the information for the page you're currently on:

```
$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE title = '$current_page'")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the returned $stmt results contain both 'home' and 'contact' titles.

Try this:

```
$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT(title) as title FROM table WHERE title IS NOT NULL")->fetchAll();
foreach ($stmt as $tag) {
    var_dump($tag['title']);
}
```

and you will get a better understand on what data is being returned.

Comment: The result is: string(6) "home" string(4) "contact". Then what do i do?

Comment: @user1541121 Change your SELECT query so it only selects the row for the page you're interested in.

Comment: @Barmar Actually i can't do it, `title` was just a example. I don't want do specify the record on the query, i want my query to work with  the value of a column. Example: `if ($tag['title'] == 'home')`

Comment: If you don't specify the record in the query, you get all records.

Comment: @user1541121 what are you trying to achieve? Understanding this would help us suggest you a better solution.

Comment: @mkveksas i solved my problem, according with the comments above my question, thanks for help!